# Convert string to dict and sort in ascending

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary

```
{“timid”:”34567”, “version”:”1”,”binary_data”:”fsfdsfsdfasdfasdfsfasfdsa”,”seqNumber”:”101”}

{“timid”:”32567”, “version”:”1”,”binary_data”:”fsfsdfdsfdsfdsfsfsdfpipi”,”seqNumber”:”109”}

{“timid”:”36567”, “version”:”1”,”binary_data”:”fsfdsfsdfafsdfdsfsfasdfsfasfdsa”,”seqNumber”:”100”}
```

I have a file with strings in the above format, I want to convert the string into dictionary and sort the records using seq number in python3.
I have been trying below method, but not successful. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance

```
import json
import ast
filename = 'u-data'

with open(filename) as f:
    string1 = f.read()
    # ast.literal_eval(string1)
    data = dict(string1.split(':') for x in string1.split(','))
    f.close()
    # string1 = string1[1:-2]
print(data)
```

Comment: did you try `json.loads(string1)`?

Comment: Could be the curly quotes, which are always annoying.

Comment: Read the file one line at a time and call json.loads(line) if line is not empty... Then do your data conversion

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
data = ast.literal_eval(string1)
```

What happened when you used ast.literal_eval()?

EDIT

First do this:

```
string1 = string1.replace('“',"'").replace('”',"'")
```

You have some double quotes that are messing things up. Then run:

```
data = ast.literal_eval(string1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution. I use `pandas` for convenience but this is easily adaptable to a non-pandas variant.

```
from io import StringIO
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

mystr = StringIO("""{'timid':'34567', 'version':'1','binary_data':'fsfdsfsdfasdfasdfsfasfdsa','seqNumber':'101'}
{'timid':'32567', 'version':'1','binary_data':'fsfsdfdsfdsfdsfsfsdfpipi','seqNumber':'109'}
{'timid':'36567', 'version':'1','binary_data':'fsfdsfsdfafsdfdsfsfasdfsfasfdsa','seqNumber':'100'}
""")

# read file
df = pd.read_csv(mystr, header=None, sep='|')

# create list of dictionaries
lst = df[0].map(literal_eval).tolist()

# sort list
res = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: int(x['seqNumber']))

# [{'binary_data': 'fsfdsfsdfafsdfdsfsfasdfsfasfdsa',
#   'seqNumber': '100',
#   'timid': '36567',
#   'version': '1'},
#  {'binary_data': 'fsfdsfsdfasdfasdfsfasfdsa',
#   'seqNumber': '101',
#   'timid': '34567',
#   'version': '1'},
#  {'binary_data': 'fsfsdfdsfdsfdsfsfsdfpipi',
#   'seqNumber': '109',
#   'timid': '32567',
#   'version': '1'}]
```